# how to invoke javascript function and variable from another javascript file

Tags: javascript, json

I'm building an application to check if users follow the instruction provided to take photo and match the facial recognition. 
I have 8 instructions for users such as checking whether they are smiling while taking photo, since our facial recognition is achieved through online API 'Skybiometry'. So we have to get the according value from its JSON value as follows, in another html file, I need to call VerifyFace() function and get message and result variable in another javascript file if result is unsuccessful. I call the function as `VerifyFace();` and followed by `result;` and `message;`. However the code is not working.

```
function ValuesToCheck(){
    Msgs = Msgs(); 
    RandomMsg = RandomMsg();
    if (RandomMsg == Msgs[0] || RandomMsg == Msgs[1]){
      var check = photos[0].tags[0].attributes[0].glasses[0];
    } else if (RandomMsg == Msgs[2] || RandomMsg == Msgs[3]) {
      var check = photos[0].tags[0].attributes[0].smiling[0];
    } else if (RandomMsg == Msgs[4] || RandomMsg == Msgs[5]) {
      var check = photos[0].tags[0].attributes[0].lips[0];
    } else if (RandomMsg == Msgs[6] || RandomMsg == Msgs[7]) {
      var check = photos[0].tags[0].attributes[0].eyes[0];
    }
    check = "facesDet." + check;
    return check;
}

var result = "Unsuccessful";
var message = "You didn't follow the instruction, please try again.";

function VerifyFace(){
    Msgs = Msgs(); 
    RandomMsg = RandomMsg();
    check = ValuesToCheck();
    var value = check + ".value";
    var confidence = check + ".confidence";
    if (RandomMsg == Msgs[0] && value == true && confidence >= 50){
      console("Users followed the instruction!");
    } else {
      result;
      message;
    } 

    if (RandomMsg == Msgs[1] && value == false && confidence < 50){
      console("Users followed the instruction!");
    } else {
      result;
      message;
    }

    if (RandomMsg == Msgs[2] && value == true && confidence >= 50){
      console("Users followed the instruction!");
    } else {
      result;
      message;
    } 
}
```

Below is the JSON output from 'Skybiometry':

```
{
"photos" : [
    {
        "url" : "http://tinyurl.com/673cksr",
        "pid" : "F@0c95576847e9cd7123f1e304476b59ae_59ec9bb2ad15f",
        "width" : 375,
        "height" : 409,
        "tags" : [
            {
                "tid" : "TEMP_F@0c95576847e9cd7123f1e304b1dcbe53_59ec9bb2ad15f_56.53_40.83_0_1",
                "recognizable" : true,
                "confirmed" : false,
                "manual" : false,
                "width" : 30.67,
                "height" : 28.12,
                "center" : { "x" : 56.53, "y" : 40.83},
                "eye_left" : { "x" : 66.93, "y" : 33.99},
                "eye_right" : { "x" : 51.73, "y" : 33.99},
                "yaw" : -16,
                "roll" : 0,
                "pitch" : 0,
                "attributes" : {
                    "face" : { "value" : "true", "confidence" : 82 },
                    "gender" : { "value" : "female", "confidence" : 80 },
                    "glasses":{"value" : "true", "confidence" : 100},
                    "dark_glasses":{"value" : "true", "confidence" : 72},
                    "smiling":{"value" : "false", "confidence" : 35}
                }
            }
        ]
    }
],
"status" : "success",
"usage" : {
    "used" : 1,
    "remaining" : 99,
    "limit" : 100,
    "reset_time_text" : "Fri, 21 September 2012 12:57:19 +0000",
    "reset_time" : 1348232239
}
}
```

Comment: The expressions `result;` and `message;` don't actually do anything. What makes you think it isn't working.

Comment: Please indent your code. We can't read it (and I doubt you can either).

Comment: Try "debugging" your program. SO is not really good at debugging programs. Your debugger is much better at it. See http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: `console('...')` probably produces errors too

Comment: Hi so sorry for not formatting it properly, I was indenting the code to post it, neglecting the neat format. Just edited it to be neat, please indicate it again if there's other things need to b edited.

Comment: The first comment is all you need to read

Comment: @Quentin since the content of the result and message variable is not showing anything in other file.

Comment: @vivixu — The expressions `result'` and `message'` don't actually do anything … and that includes showing you their content, so how are you looking at their content?

Comment: @Quentin I tested it by `alert(message);`, but there's nothing comes out. So I'm thinking am I invoking the variable in the correct wat.

Comment: @torazaburo Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @vivixu — Based on your description of what you've done, that should not happen. Something is missing from it. You need to provide a proper test case: http://sscce.org/

Comment: @Quentin so my code is correct? We can call a function and declare variables in the function?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think these lines:

```
Msgs = Msgs(); 
RandomMsg = RandomMsg();
```

are doing what you want, since you said they were variables and not functions.

If `Msgs` and `RandomMsg` truly are global variables, then you can omit those lines and just use `Msgs` and `RandomMsg` in your functions.

Another possibility, if, for example, you want to insure that your functions don't change the globals is something like this:

```
var Msgs      = window.Msgs      || '';
var RandomMsg = window.RandomMsg || '';
```

which makes a copy of the globasl as locals (or the empty string if they don't exist).

Also these lines:

```
result;
message;
```

have no visible effect.  Do you want to put them someplace on the page or something like:

```
alert('result: ' + result + ", message = " + message);
```

at least?

Comment: Just to declare in case you might not know, my `Msgs()` function will return the value of Msgs so I use `Msgs()` to get variable `Msgs`, just variable and function share the same name. Am I correct for this knowledge?

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to reuse names.  `var theMsgs = Msgs();` (or similar) is less troublesome.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. When I call this function in another javascript file, can I use the variables used in the function, as in `message` and `result` in this case.